# Getting W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request POST when working with Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

The problem is when

```
I try to upload an image to firebase storage sometimes it successfully uploads the image but most of the time it keep saying



 *****/com.example.firebasestoragedemo W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/*myproject_name/some_more_extension.
when I enter to this link I found 
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}
but I have enabled signInWithEmailAndPassword in my onStart(){...} function and my security rule is here
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write : if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}*****
```

These two exceptions I get..

java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to firebasestorage.googleapis.com/....
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xe096ebb8: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

my code is truly current otherwise it couldn't be working sometimes. I think the problem is somewhere else in most probably in Firebase.

Please help me out. It will will be a great pleasure if you try to help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue when I tried to access "Firebase Storage" over mobile data. (from Bangladesh). Then I tried it over Broad Band internet connection and everything worked fine.

Comment: I have the same error when my wifi is off and I have slow mobile internet.. but that's not a really good behaviour from firebase I think

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this, my problem was using an emulator

Works fine on a physical device